# How do I correctly close a pipe shared by two processes?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I'm attempting to use pipes to communicate between processes in python. These processes will be called from different threads, and so may not have direct access to the `Popen` object for each process. I've written script below, as a simple proof of concept, but have found that my recieving process never terminates.

```
import os
import subprocess
import traceback
import shlex


if __name__ == '__main__':
    (fd_out, fd_in) = os.pipe()
    pipe_in = os.fdopen(fd_in, 'w')
    pipe_out = os.fdopen(fd_out, 'r')
    file_out = open('outfile.data', 'w+')

    cmd1 = 'cat ' + ' '.join('parts/%s' % x for x in sorted(os.listdir('parts')))
    cmd2 = 'pbzip2 -d -c'
    pobj1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd1), stdout=pipe_in)
    pobj2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd2), stdin=pipe_out,
                                                stdout=file_out)


    print 'closing pipe in'                                                     
    pipe_in.close()                                                             
    print 'closing pipe out'                                                    
    pipe_out.close()                                                            
    print 'closing file out'                                                    
    file_out.close()                                                            
    print 'waiting on process 2'                                                
    pobj2.wait()                                                                
    print 'done'
```

This runs correctly in many ways. The data chunks get piped to the 2nd process, and the 2nd process decompresses the stream and writes it to a file. I can watch the processes until they seem to be just waiting (and doing nothing), terminate the 2nd process, and the file seems to be completely written.

So, I'm wondering why the 2nd process never terminates. It seems that it never realizes that the input stream has been closed. How do I close the pipe properly, so that the process knows to terminate?

```
david_clymer@zapazoid:/home/tmp/db$ python test.py
closing pipe in
closing pipe out
closing file out
waiting on process 2
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python test.py
david_clymer@zapazoid:/home/tmp/db$ bg
[1]+ python test.py &
david_clymer@zapazoid:/home/tmp/db$ jobs -l
[1]+ 31533 Running                 python test.py &
david_clymer@zapazoid:/home/tmp/db$ ps -fp 31533
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1000     31533 22536  0 15:22 pts/2    00:00:00 python test.py
david_clymer@zapazoid:/home/tmp/db$ lsof |grep $(pwd)
bash       3432       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
bash      22536       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
python    31533       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535       david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31536 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31536 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31537 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31537 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31538 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31538 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31539 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31539 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31540 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31540 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31541 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31541 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31542 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31542 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31543 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31543 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
pbzip2    31535 31544 david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
pbzip2    31535 31544 david_clymer    1u      REG              253,3 12255300000 397270 /home/tmp/db/outfile.data
lsof      31599       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
grep      31600       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
lsof      31602       david_clymer  cwd       DIR              253,3      483328 408117 /home/tmp/db
david_clymer@zapazoid:/home/tmp/db$ strace -p 31533
Process 31533 attached - interrupt to quit
wait4(31535, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 31533 detached
```

I imagine I am doing something stupid. I'd like to know what, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second process is probably inheriting the input end of the pipe, which therefore never gets closed. I'm not a Python expert, but perhaps it's possible to avoid this is by `Popen`ing the second process first with a `stdin=PIPE`, then `Popen` the first process with the second processes's `.stdin` as its `stdout`. (`Popen` probably arranges for the process not to have a handle to the input end of the pipe that it creates internally.)

In order to work around the file descriptor inheritance, call subprocess using `close_fds=True`:

```
pobj2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd2),
                         stdin=pipe_out,
                         stdout=file_out,
                         close_fds=True)
```

Comment: Ahah! So it turns out that using `close_fds=True` solves that problem, and causes it to work as expected.

Comment: @vezult Thanks, I didn't know about close_fds, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

with `subprocess.Popen()`, you shouldn't need to mess about with manually calling `os.pipe()` and such.

```
pobj1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'] + ['parts/' + x for x in sorted(os.listdir('parts'))],
                         stdout=PIPE)
pobj2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('pbzip2 -d -c'),
                         stdin=pobj1.stdout,
                         stdout=open('outfile.data', 'w+'))
```

should do what you want.

Comment: As described in my ticket, the use of Popen object attributes is not a solution, as they won't be available in separate threads. I'm not calling `os.popen()`, so I'm not sure what you are referring to there.

Comment: Apologies, I meant `os.pipe()`.

Comment: I was also unclear what you meant by "calling" a process in your original question. If you mean that you want several threads to be able to send input into the pipe for your subprocess to read, it seems no harder to me to pass around pobject.stdin than a file descriptor or stream that you fdopen from a descriptor.